# PaperJS: Events are caught when I'm outside the canvas

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm working in a tool to draw in a canvas using the framework Paper.js

I got an issue using iPad. When I'm drawing with one finger, that works. When I'm drawing with two fingers, one in the canvas and one outside the canvas, the second finger event is caught by the event onMouseDrag, and that put some stroke from the first finger to the second finger, not a good behaviour for me.

Example:

[image]

At the beginning, I start to draw with one finger. After I put the second finger outside the canvas and I continue to move my first finger. This is what happen.

Do you have any idea to avoid event when I'm outside the canvas?

Thanks.

Comment: But you want this to happen if the second finger is inside the canvas?

Comment: No, I just want only one finger. But right now, I don't understand why the second figer is detected because it's outside the canvas. When I put my two fingers on the canvas, only one finger draw. It's what I want with the second finger outside the canvas too, but I got this.

Comment: @alexmngn Did you get a solutions to this? I am also facing this issue.

Comment: Me facing same issue even with latest paper.js. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the finger outside to be detected, limit the target to your canvas.

```
 var canvasElement = document.getElementById('canvasId') //or element
    tool.onMouseDrag = function(event) {
           if (event.event.target === canvasElement) { //my target canvas was nested like this
               path.add(event.point);
               path.smooth();
           }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you could test event.point.isInside(view.bounds).  This will likely kill your performance if you test it while drawing, but you could cull the points after you're finished.

Comment: No! because that draw from the first finger to the border of the canvas... I'm seeking a solution to disable the detection of the second finger.